# Register iPhone application

Tags: iphone

What are the step-by-step instructions to register an iPhone application in the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS))?

I created an iPhone sample application. I want to deploy it on a real device.

But i don’t know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by visiting [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/appstore/submission.html) on the app submission process.